# Is there a way to avoid "newline in string" errors in awk?

Tags: bash, awk

How are cmdline args containing newline chars passed to `awk`? See two examples below:

```
awk -v s='text' 'BEGIN { print(s) }'

text

awk -v s=$'\n''text' 'BEGIN { print(s) }'

awk: newline in string 
text... at source line 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have would work as-is with gawk. With OSX (BSD) awk like you're using, either don't put a linefeed character in the string.

```
$ awk -v s='\ntext' 'BEGIN{ print s }'

text
```

or escape it:

```
awk -v s='\
text' 'BEGIN{ print s }'

text
```

or (portably with any awk) don't pass it using -v but as an argument instead:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{s=ARGV[1]; ARGV[1]=""; print s }' $'\n''text'

text
```