# awk adding a block of text with multiple newlines

Tags: bash, awk

I have a template file `template.yml` as below:

```
Subnet1
    Type: AWS::Subnet
    Properties:
       name: sub1
       ...
       vpc: myVpc
...
LogicalIp1:
    Type: AWS::CIDR::IP
    Properties:
        IPv4: yes
        ...
        vpc: myVpc
LogicalIp2:
    Type: AWS::CIDR::IP
    Properties:
        IPv4: yes
        ...
        vpc: myVpc
...
...
Vpc:
    Type: AWS::VPC
    Properties:
        name: myVpc
        ...
        ...
```

`...` means there are other texts in between with same indentation.

I want to add a few blocks of properties under `Properties:` for LogicalIp1 and LogicalIp2 with contents from text file (each having new line).

So my text file `props.txt` looks as below:

```
        key1: val1
        key2: val2
        ...
        ...
```

I am trying to use awk as below inside a shell script:

```
# read the file content to a var
var=`cat props.txt`

awk -v value="$var" '1; /LogicalIp1:/ {logicalIp1 = 1;}; logicalIp1 && /Properties:/ && !wrote { wrote = 1; print value}' template.yml 


awk -v value="$var" '1; /LogicalIp2:/ {logicalIp2 = 1;}; logicalIp2 && /Properties:/ && !wrote { wrote = 1; print value}' template.yml
```

However when I try this, I get the below error:

```
awk: newline in string 
text... at source line 4
```

Is there anything I am missing? How can I achieve adding block with new lines with `print` inside awk?

Comment: `awk` is not the right tool for complex editing of yml file. Please consider `yq`

Comment: Could you please make your samples more clear by removing `....` lines for better understanding of question.

Comment: Btw, your code works as-is on `gawk`, `mawk` and `busybox awk`. It failed on `awk version 20121220`. which is probably pretty close to awk used in OS X.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50555780/is-there-a-way-to-avoid-newline-in-string-errors-in-awk